# arc length parametric curves

Tags: calculus

Find the length of the curve:

$x=t+\sin t$, $y=\cos t$, $(0\le t\le\pi)$

and I got this formula:

$$L=\int_0^\pi \sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2 } \,dt$$

so now I'm wondering, how can I simplify this so I can integrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = 1+\cos(t)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -\sin(t)$$
So
$$L = \int_{0}^{\pi}{\sqrt{{\left(1+\cos(t) \right)}^{2}+{\left(-\sin(t) \right)}^{2}}}\,dt$$
$$L = \int_{0}^{\pi}{\sqrt{2+2\cos(t)}}\,dt$$
Now use: $$\cos(t) = {\cos}^{2} \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)- {\sin}^{2} \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$
$$1+\cos(t) = 2{\cos}^{2} \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$
So 
$$L = \int_{0}^{\pi}2\left|\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right|\,dt$$
It remains to solve this last integral